# Can $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ be represented by sets of complex numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, reference-request, finite-fields, coding-theory

Is there any natural way of defining a structure in $\mathbb{C}$ (or some domain $D$ over complex n-vectors, or similar) so that it resembles a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

For example, I am hoping something like the following can be done:

> A set of vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ together with two certain operations is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, and the operations have something to do with complex vector arithmetic.

I am not sure if such simple structures can be rich enough to capture the details of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, though.

Comment: I don't see the need to go to $\Bbb{C}^n$ in particular to get $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. You can do the following though. Let $\zeta$ be a complex root of unity of order $L=p^n-1$, say $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/L}$. Then the subring of compex numbers, $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$ has a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, containing the prime number $p$, such that the quotient ring
$\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]/\mathfrak{p}\simeq \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. Mind you, for specific choices of $p$ and $n$ we get away with using a simpler subring in place of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$, but this is a general recipe.

Comment: "together with certain operations" is probably far too broad (just import the operations from $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ to begin with!).